# why is time difference in python returning strings and not calculating differences?

Tags: python-3.x, string, time

Can someone explain why is this code returning following result and not the difference in time.

```
import time

value = 0.0

def set_value():
    value = time.time()
    print(value)

def timelimit():
    diff = time.time() - value
    print(diff)

set_value()
time.sleep(1)
timelimit();
```

Results

```
1603633556.3795211
1603633557.3804882
```

There is clearly 1 seconds difference but the result is still the time and not the difference

Answer (score 1):

Never mind . Just found out that I missed the
'global value' in the set_value() function